# C++ do while loop not responding

Tags: c++

Hey guys i have a do while loop its simple but the program goes into a none responsive state while running it heres the loop.

```
bool SetTime(const int hour,const int min,HWND sec)
{
    do 
    {
        time_t s=time(0);  
        tm t=*localtime(&s);
        itoa(t.tm_sec,buf3,10);
        SetWindowText(sec,buf3);
        if (hour == t.tm_hour && min == t.tm_min)
        {
              exit(0);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
     }
     while( hour == t.tm_hour && min >t.tm_min);
 }
```

it runs every second and when it reaches the proper time it stops

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler? On which platform?

Comment: You are probably hanging your program main thread in this task. Try using multithread.

Comment: Operating in Windows 7 using Dev C++

Comment: When the first two parameters are ints called "hour" and "min", it's quite a surprise that "sec" is an HWND.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Win32 due to the HWND, you are blocking the event loop. If you want to defer an operation look at using a timer.

Comment: thanks I'll try,should i try taking out the HWND all together ?

Comment: @user2167455: Rather than comparing for equality you may want to check for greater than.  The probability of the OS scheduling your task at the exact hour and minute may be low depending on what other tasks and programs are running.

Comment: @Gary thanks for the Tip, SetTimer() was the last type of loop I hadn't tried because I thought it might return the same type of not responding action, but it went through fine thanks for the assist, as for all those negative for my question, thank you cause negativity only make me work harder :)